# Is it possible to have freemarker's <@spring.showErrors to display errors in a div instead of span

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, freemarker

Code:

```
<@spring.formInput 'myForm.spouseEmail' 'id="spouseEmail" class="text"'/>
<@spring.showErrors ', ' 'error'/>
```

Output:

```
<span class="error">not a well-formed email address</span>
```

What I want:

```
<div class="error">not a well-formed email address</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

@Mike: it seems you have troubles understanding the nature of macros. They are already-written freemarker script to make your life easier. You can always [write a customed one](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_userdefdir.html).

Some people think it obvious, but I myself find that it's not easy to know how to view the spring-freemarker macros source code. You can navigate to package `org/springframework/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.jar/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/spring.ftl` in Eclipse's "Referenced Libraries".

Here's the macro "showErrors" gotten from "spring.ftl":

```
<#macro showErrors separator classOrStyle="">
    <#list status.errorMessages as error>
    <#if classOrStyle == "">
        <b>${error}</b>
    <#else>
        <#if classOrStyle?index_of(":") == -1><#assign attr="class"><#else><#assign attr="style"></#if>
        <span ${attr}="${classOrStyle}">${error}</span>
    </#if>
    <#if error_has_next>${separator}</#if>
    </#list>
</#macro>
```

To achieve your goal, it's very simple: just write a custom macro which is exactly like the code above, replace `span` by `div`

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can easily write your own macro to do whatever you want. Get your inspiration from `spring.showErrors` itself.